# graphic does not appear

Tags: graphics

The problem is the following: I have included a graphic (png) and get no error message, but the picture does not appear on the pdf?
The .png file is correct, I do not know what could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{makeidx}         

\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program

\definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{.9,.9,.95}%
\definecolor{shadethmcolor2}{rgb}{1,.925,.545}%

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{:}{.5em}{}%

\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{beispiel}{Beispiel}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor2,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{formel}{Formel}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Zinsrechnung.png}
\caption{geometrisches Mittel}\label{fig:zins}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, revise your `.log` file. If you can't find anything wrong with it, paste it here too.

Comment: Ok, I checked the .log file and searched for the picture but there where no problems - no error messages or things like that?

Comment: I tried with smaller scale values but it also does not work. The caption is also not appearing - it is just not there?!

thanks to you helping me

Comment: yeah, but this was the error message, when I compiled it wrong with TexStudio! When I do it correct I do not get an error message and the pdf is built without a problem but the picture does not appear!

Comment: Please, paste the `log` you get when you compile it "correct". Also, please, in order to keep clean the question, delete all these temporary comments. I will do the same with mine.

Comment: I've removed an answer which contained a partial log, as it was rather long and did not contain anything useful. Please cut down your example to a minimum, and then post the log for that minimal example.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem - your example is _not_ a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

### Graphic does not appear

What could be the cause for a graphic not to appear?

It may be usefull for all readers of this broad headline of the question to collect all frequent causes for invisible graphics. So please go ahead and add your experience.

- Graphic could be off the page; possible check: make the graphic much smaller and have a second look (`\includegraphics[scaled=0.1]{picture}`), put the graphic into the middle of the paper (`\vfill\includegraphics{picture}\vfill`), and make the paper larger (e.g. paper a2).
- `graphicx` package is in `draft` or `demo` modes. Or the main `\documentclass` uses `draft` option (this is passed to all `\usepackage`s)
- The graphic file cannot be found, but the error is not seen because the user is using some kind of script which uses `batchmode`. Possible check: look for errors in the `.log` file.

Comment: You forgot the most important source: The problem can be due to something unrelated to the graphic. So the first step is to comment the `\includegraphics` and check if the document compiles.